# Finding a specific value for each row in a Dataframe from another Dataframe's column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for alternate ways to replace functions used in Excel with Python, especially with Pandas. One of the functions is COUNTIFS(), which I have been primarily using to locate specific row values in a fixed range. This is mainly used to determine, whether the specific values in one column are present in the other column, or not.

An example in Excel would look something like this:

[image]

The code for the first row (column: col1_in_col2):

=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$6,A2)

I have tried to recreate the function in Pandas, only with the difference that the two columns can be found in two different DataFrames and the DataFrames are inside a dictionary (bigdict). The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

bigdict = {"df1": pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["0110200_2016", "011037_2016", "011037_2016", "0111054_2016"]}), "df2": pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["011037_2016", "0111054_2016", "011109_2016", "0111268_2016"]})}

bigdict.get("df1")["df1_in_df2"] = bigdict.get("df1").apply(lambda x: 1 if x["col1"] in bigdict.get("df2")["col1"] else 0, axis=1)
```

In the example above, the first row should get a return value of zero, while the other rows should get return values of 1, since it can be found in the other DataFrame's column. However, the return value is 0 for every row.

Comment: Hi, have you tried to use `groupby` with `transform('counts')`?
If you are using two DataFrames, append the column you use as range from the second one to your first DataFrame, then use that column as parameter for your groupby.

Comment: If you are interested on the timing for various methods you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the same as @Ashwini's answer but you get rid of `np.where` and `iloc` which could make it more readable and eventually faster.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["0110200_2016", "011037_2016",
                             "011037_2016", "0111054_2016"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["011037_2016", "0111054_2016",
                              "011109_2016", "0111268_2016"]})

df1['df1_in_df2'] = df1["col1"].isin(df2['col1'].values).astype("int8")
```

**UPDATE**

## Timing

Here I try to compare 4 methods @vlemaistre, @Ashwini, @SamLegesse and mine.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create fake data
n = int(1e6)
n1 = int(1e4)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["col1"] = ["{:012}".format(i) for i in range(n)]

df2 = df.sample(n1)
toRemove = df2.sample(n1//2).index
df1 = df[~df.index.isin(toRemove)].sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

# backup dataframe
df0 = df1.copy()
```

### vlemaistre

```py
bigdict = {"df1": df1, "df2": df2}
```

```py
%%time
bigdict['df1']['df1_in_df2'] = [1 if x in bigdict['df2']['col1'].values else 0
                                for x in bigdict['df1']['col1']]
```

```sh
CPU times: user 4min 53s, sys: 3.08 s, total: 4min 56s
Wall time: 4min 41s
```

### SamLegesse

```py
def countif(x,col):
    if x in col.values:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    return
df1 = df0.copy()
```

```py
%%time
df1['df1_in_df2'] = df1['col1'].apply(countif, col=df2['col1'])
```

```sh
CPU times: user 4min 48s, sys: 2.66 s, total: 4min 50s
Wall time: 4min 38s
```

### Ashwini

```py
df1 = df0.copy()
```

```py
%%time
df1['df1_in_df2'] = np.where(df1.iloc[:,0].isin(list(df2.iloc[:,0])),1,0)
```

```sh
CPU times: user 167 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 167 ms
Wall time: 165 ms
```

### rpanai

This is perfectly on par with Ashwini's solution

```py
df1 = df0.copy()
```

```py
%%time
df1['df1_in_df2'] = df1["col1"].isin(df2['col1'].values).astype("int8")
```

```sh
CPU times: user 152 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 152 ms
Wall time: 150 ms
```

### Conclusion

The vectorial methods are (at least) 1684x faster than the one using `apply`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. I unstacked your dictionary into two dataframes and compared its values.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["0110200_2016", "011037_2016", "011037_2016", "0111054_2016"]})
df2= pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["011037_2016", "0111054_2016", "011109_2016", "0111268_2016"]})

df1['df1_in_df2'] = np.where(df1.iloc[:,0].isin(list(df2.iloc[:,0])),1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is way to do it using a list comprehension :

```
bigdict['df1']['df1_in_df2'] = [1 if x in bigdict['df2']['col1'].values else 0
                                for x in bigdict['df1']['col1']]
```

---

Output :

```
           col1  df1_in_df2
0  0110200_2016           0
1   011037_2016           1
2   011037_2016           1
3  0111054_2016           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way in my opinion would be to make a generic function that you can apply anytime you want to do the equivalent of an excel countif().

```
import pandas as pd

def countif(x,col):
    if x in col.values:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    return

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["0110200_2016", "011037_2016", "011037_2016", "0111054_2016"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["011037_2016", "0111054_2016", "011109_2016", "0111268_2016"]})

df1['df1_in_df2'] = df1['col1'].apply(countif, col=df2['col1'])
```

**EDIT:**

As rpanai mentioned in the comments, apply is known to have performance issues as your data grows. Using numpy vectorization would provide a large performance boost. Here is a modified version of Ashwini's answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def countif(df1, df2, col1, col2, name):
    df1[name] = np.where(df1[col1].isin(list(df2[col2])),1,0)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["0110200_2016", "011037_2016", "011037_2016", "0111054_2016"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["011037_2016", "0111054_2016", "011109_2016", "0111268_2016"]})

countif(df1,df2,'col1','col1','df1_in_df2')

print(df1)
#            col1  df1_in_df2
# 0  0110200_2016           0
# 1   011037_2016           1
# 2   011037_2016           1
# 3  0111054_2016           1
```

Comment: Pandas performances 101: Try to avoid `apply` [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html)